# What is a convenient way to save canvas drawings on a MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html5-canvas

I have a board game application and I want to extend that application to enable the user to make drawings on the game area through canvas and save game state, including the canvas drawings on a MySQL database, and access those screenshots later.  Now I was searching for methods how I could save a canvas drawing on a database. I thought I might extract the ImageData object through the function getImageData(). Now that Object includes a big array which eventually represents the pixels of the canvas image. I could convert the data included in the array to text to be able to save it on the database. When I want to access that canvas drawing later, I can call that text representing the pixel array from the database and convert it to an array again on the client side to be able to build the ImageData object again and put it into the canvas.

Now it turned out that the text representing the array could have a size of 5 mega bytes! I might want to call dozents of screenshots for a user from the server, so dozents of 5 mega bytes.

***My question is:*** Is there a more efficient way to save canvas drawing on the server? Is the described way good or efficient, could it be made in a better way?

Comment: mysql does have binary blob types. How big is a binary version of the canvas? Filesystems are pretty good at storing arbitrary files of various lengths. Database's can store filenames with at most a few tens of bytes.

Comment: You can save images in base64 format inside your sql table. When you're working on canvas convert it into base64 string and save those string into your table.
You can encode and decode your string.
For reference check this base64 encoder and decoder link- https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: I wish this question were still open; it has a legit answer. In the browser you can export canvas contents as .png files with [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) or as [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob). Those won't be insanely large for canvases with modest line drawings. You can then put them into MySQL TEXT or BLOB columns. Using a DBMS for that sort of thing can cause performance problems, but it does work.

Comment: @O.Jones I agree with you. The question contains very little details, and no code, but answers, like yours, are certainly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally wouldn't store 5 MB images in a database, you would store the image as a file on the server, and put an entry in the database that refers to that file.

When storing image data you can use compression. ZIP for instance, but image formats like JPEG have build-in compression.

The best way to do this, however, is not to store the image, but remember the state of the game and the input from the user. This requires far less storage space. You can reconstruct the canvas using this data.

Comment: But how I could remember the content of the canvas, when I have a free drawn shapes on it, It is not simply a rectangle or a line where I could only save the length of edges and the coordinates to reconstruct them later?

Comment: @Ahmad It depends own what software you use for the drawings. Your question doesn't include any details about that, which makes it impossible for me to address your question here.

Comment: I ended up having only canvas texts, rectangles and arrows, I didn't implement free drawing feature. So I saved only a state like the length and color of the rectangle edges. This required far less memory as you suggested.